# How to route my android app's internet data through a specific port?

Tags: android, android-studio, xmpp, smack, tor

i am connecting to tor network using onion proxy manager from here:
https://github.com/jehy/Tor-Onion-Proxy-Library

which return me the port where tor is listening to.
I need to route my xmpp data through this port so that i can connect to some xmpp server having a .onion domain. I am using smack-android 4.1.0 to handle xmpp communication. But XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration class does not provide any option to provide routing port details. How to go about this?